# Shinydashboard: remove white space under dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am still fairly new to shinydashboard, but am struggling with the following problem:

Shinydashboard does not fill the whole screen and always leaves some whitespace, see pictures:

[Desktop Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMiez.png)

[Mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGih7.png)

This is me just using the most basic shinydashboard code:

UI.R

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
server <- function(input, output) { }
```

I have tried searching everywhere, but it seems nobody has this problem. Btw, I only have this problem on my browsers. Through the R console I don't get any white space.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem, the app displays fine with RStudio internal viewer, as well as Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome. It has nothing to do with the code unfortunately, but with the screen resolution (I use 1920x1080 on a 13 inch screen). When I resize the screen, sometimes the whitespace goes away and sometimes it even gets worse.

Did nobody else encounter this problem?